# SharePoint Online MODIFIED BY ME and Throttling (5000 item) issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a ContentBy Query webpart which basically pulls all documents from the entire site collection (which in total contains 5500 documents) and I have filter in place to only show documents modified by me and in this case only 10 of them out of the total 5500. But Even after this I get following error:

```
Your query returned a greater number of results than the web application's query throttling limit. Please adjust the configuration of this Web Part or increase the throttling limit.
```

I am not sure why this has started coming up on this webpart where all I have is to show Documents modified by me and it has a filter in place (ModifiedBy == Me).

Any help on this, this is all done in SHAREPOINT ONLINE.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, You can use the Content by Search Web Part (CSWP), which uses the search engine instead and it is not affected by the List View Threshold.

The following article for your reference.

[Content By Search Web Part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135472/list-throttling-threshold-workaround-for-cqwp)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the issue here is this SPO and indexing is not that quick and we wanted to make those items appear quickly (a delay of 10-15mins is fine but unfortunately the crawl schedule is not quick I guess with SharePoint Online so we get delayed and dont see the results quickly.